# how to get schema.org multiple keys for award category

Tags: schema.org

I am trying to create a schema.org in ld+json and I have all the data working so far.

I am trying to create an array for the award field for a person so I can list multiple awards.

If I do "award" : "some award" as a solo item it works. But I am having trouble creating multiple awards.

I have tried

"award": [
{
"@type" : "award",
"name" : "award name"
}
]

But I get a validation error that *award is not a known valid target type for the award property.*

I have checked out schema.org and tried looking it up online, but have not found anything helpful.

Has anyone had any experience with getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [award](https://schema.org/award)'s docs:

> Values expected to be one of these types
>
> Text

so, there's no `@type`, just plain text, so you can try listing awards as strings in an [array](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#terminology):

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "award": ["Award", "Another award", "And another one"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am new to using the schema.org information and could not figure out what was obviously a really simple answer. Thanks a million.